# Binary search on a linked list of nodes using a HashMap in O(logN) Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, hashmap, binary-search

Can you do a binary search on a sorted linked list of nodes (objects) in a time complexity of O(logN) ? I know that Linked Lists don't support direct indexing, so you can't do something like list[3] or list.get(3), so basically you need to iterate through all the elements of the list to find the index of the middle element. But what if you have at your disposal an additional data structure, like a HashMap(key = index,value = node) ? Could this work?

Example :
Let's say we have the list:

```
1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 9 -> 14 -> 18
```

And the HashMap used to get nodes in O(1):

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 4
2 -> 7
3 -> 9
4 -> 14
5 -> 18
```

Now if we want to find 14 we do:

```
binarySearch(0,5) : middle = 2 -> get node 7 from the Hashmap. 14 > 7 so ->
binarySearch(3,5) : middle = 4 -> get node 14 from the Hashmap. 14 == 14 ->Voila
```

Of course, to build this hashmap you would have to do N operations, so O(N) time complexity but if you already have the HashMap could this work?

If yes, can't you use this approach to do an insertion sort in O(nlogn) time complexity on a Linked List with an additional HashMap ?

Basically:

```
 1. for each element ( O(n) )
    2. find the position of the element in the list in O(logN) with binary search that uses the Hashmap to get the element at the middle position in O(1).
    3. insert the element in the Linked List in O(1)
    4. insert the (index,element) into the Hashmap in O(1)
```

---

O(nlogn) time complexity. Or am I doing/assuming something wrong?

Comment: Yes, such a thing would work. You could even use an array rather than a hash map for the indirect index. You only need to build the index once at startup, and whenever you add or remove a node. If the list doesn't change very often, then this is a good way to go.

Comment: Yes, I realized later that the first question (with binary search in (O(logN) time complexity on a linked list) is stupid because I'm actually doing the binary search on an array, not on a linked list. And also the insertion sort won't work because when I insert the new pair in the hashmap, I also need to update the other keys (indexes) in the hashmap, and this will require O(N) time complexity...

Comment: @EmanYalpsid: It sounds like you should [write an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). :-)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is pretty good, here is how you could make it work: As key you can use the node's value. If the list node values are unique then you can use a node as value of the hash map (otherwise a list of nodes). So you can still go from node to node as usual in the list, but you can also get access by value in O(1).

You would have to update the hash map if the value changes, on insertion and removal, but everything is O(1) or O(c) where c is the max number of duplicate values in the list, if c doesn't depend on n then it is O(1) even with duplicates, otherwise O(n).